# How do I call a function using input-text (clj-webdriver)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, clojure

I have a function

```
(defn xyz
[]
...)
```

which gives value 3

How do I get this value to use in `(input-text)` using clj-webdriver

I used `(input text #abc (xyz))`

But gives me the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException,
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please supply more context, such as a minimal reproducing case (complete). Also, I don't see a function `input-text` in clj-webdriver.

Comment: @AlanThompson you can find the func here [link](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation#input-text)

Comment: @AlanThompson I need to pass a function which gives a value in `(input-text)` .so that the form field is filled with the value. I am doing testing

Answer (score 0):

Your tag and string should be strings.

```
(input-text "#abc" (str (abc)))
```